# What does u mean in regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I came across this code and I'm at loss as to what `u` means :

```
$todecode =~ s{
   %u([Dd][89a-bA-B][0-9a-fA-F]{2}) # hi
          %u([Dd][c-fC-F][0-9a-fA-F]{2})   # lo
        }{
     utf8_chr(
       0x10000_
       + (hex($1) - 0xD800) * 0x400_
       + (hex($2) - 0xDC00)
      )
        }gex;
```

Answer (score 14):

It's the letter between `t` and `v`.  (It's matching a literal `u`.)

It looks like somebody has some text with [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) surrogate pairs written out as `%uD800%uDC00`, and they're passing the decoded codepoint to the `utf8_chr` function, and substituting the result of that.